# Running grails test-app command from grails web console plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have installed the [grails web plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/console). I can now browse to :

```
localhost:8080/myappname/console
```

And I can see the console displayed over there. I have bunch of test-cases written for application. I wish I can *test* my app from this web console.

Is it possible to do so? I'm very new to grails.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no.  The grails console is meant to write groovy code that interacts with your running application.  Your running application does not include your test cases or the grails command line by default.

Long answer sort of.  Provided you have all of your projects source code available somewhere in the file system where your application is running, you could call an external process to run test-app and return the result to the user.  Here are some docs on running external processes in groovy: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy.  I suppose you could also package you application somehow to make this work, but I think doing that would be fairly complex.

I am not sure this is a good use case for the console plugin over all.  Hope this helps